# Will Testcomplete support GitLab for version controlling?

Tags: gitlab, testcomplete

I am planning to use GitLab as source code management tool for maintaining the testcases scripted using testcomplete tool. Will testcomplete support this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, TestComplete should be able to work with GitLab using its native Git support. You may miss some GitLab specific features, but there should not be problems using the standard SCC features.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry Nikolaev, Currently I am able to use GitLab using command prompt.